# (Redefinition error) Create multiple inherting classes from one baseclass in C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, redefinition

Greetings oh mighty coders,

I am a beginner and in a bit of trouble here.

There is my baseclass (*sensor.h*):

```
class sensor
{
private:
   int sensor_id;
   string sensor_name;
   string sensor_type;
   float reading;

public:

   sensor();
   sensor(int, char*, char*);
   ~sensor();

/* Few extra methods here */

};
```

... and I want to create 4 other classes that inherit from my baseclass *sensor*
(*temperaturesensor, humiditysensor*... and so on).

```
 #include "sensor.h"


class temperaturesensor:public sensor
{
public:
   Temperatursensor(int, char*,char*);
   ~Temperatursensor();

/* Few extra methods here */

};
```

Thing is: Every single one of these classes has to be in its own .cpp/.h file and then be included and used in my *main.cpp*.

```
using namespace std;
#include <xyz.h>
/* Other libaries here */
          ....
#include "temperaturesensor.h"
#include "humiditysensor.h"

int main()
{
    sensor* station[2];


    station [0] = new temperaturesensor(x,y,z);
    station [1] = new humiditysensor(x,y,z);
}
```

If I include one of them it's no biggie. However: If I use multiple ones I get an redefinition error.

error C2011: 'sensor': 'class' typeredefinition
    c:\users\name\desktop\project\sensor.h  14

```
error c2011: 'temperaturesensor' : 'class' typeredefinition
```

What can I do to workaround this? Note that I am not allowed to use *#pragma once*

Sorry for my stupidity and thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use standard *include guards* in place of the non-portable `#pragma once`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: You do have [*include guards*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) or [`#pragma once`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once) in your header files?

Comment: Do you remember, that array is numarate from 0?

Comment: And can you please edit your question *show* the errors? Copy-paste them (as text).

Comment: Since you are using `std::string` in your class, use `std::string` in your constructor's parameters.  The compiler can convert `char *` to `std::string`, so you can call the constructor with character literals.

Comment: Btw, `station[2]` is an out-of-bounds access and hence undefined behaviour. What you presumably meant was to use indices `0` and `1`, not `1` and `2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use:

```
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H

.. normal code here

#endif
```

or

```
#pragma once
```

but too, I think, that sensor schould be abstract class and you schould use virtual destructor.
One more think is that array is numerate from 0.

Comment: Good catch for indexing of the array! However, I do not see the need for an abstract base class.

Comment: Don't create symbols with a leading underscore followed by an upper-case letter, [those are reserved in all scopes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: @AGNGazer I see that class abstract sensor and specialization to particular sensors

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to use the include guards in your header class,
this is redefining your base class everytime you use it.

so, just do a

```
#pragma once
```

or a normal include guard

```
#ifndef YOURFILENAME_H
#define YOURFILENAME_H

.. normal code here

#endif
```

Then you will not have the multiple definition error.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the class `sensor` is coming from both "temperaturesensor.h"
and "humiditysensor.h". Use guards https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard or `#pragma once`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once